# JQuery Unable to retrieve data drupal services through localhost:8888

Tags: php, jquery, web-services, drupal-7

I have create a service as this tutorial say's, I can see that when I type to the browser this url:

```
http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/test_test/node/1.jsonp
```

or

```
http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/test_test/node/1.json
```

or

```
http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/test_test/system/connect.json
```

I get the json callback. But when it is in the jquery code, I get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://{localhost}:8888/drupal2/test_test/node/1.json?type=post&format=json.
>   Origin http://{localhost}:8383 is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Why is it happening?

The JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    var urlis = "http://localhost:8888/drupal2/test_test/node/1.json";
    $.getJSON(urlis, {
        type: 'post', 
        format: "json"
        }).done(function(afterdone) {
        console.log("JSONP Data");
    })
     .fail(function(error) {
        console.log("NO!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a response header on your server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: from-specific-domain.com
```

You can do that with php also:

```
<?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: from-specific-domain.com');
?>
```

Comment: So, It worked. I have created a module and the code in it is: 'function add_header_init(){header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');}' Solved the problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the cross domain AJAX. To do it in PHP, modify the scirpt:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain.com');
```

or modify your htaccess, or apache conf file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.*$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "domain.com"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Also, have a look at this article about [Cross domain AJAX request with JSON response](http://cypressnorth.com/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/)

Comment: Where should I put this line?

Comment: @Dori (not stalking you, promise ;) Use [`drupal_add_http_header()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7), probably in an implementation of `hook_init()` in a custom module

Comment: @Kasia A wildcard's probably not the best idea if just a single domain needs to be allowed

Comment: O.K I created a module and the code in it is:'function add_header_init(){
drupal_add_http_header($name="service_header", $value = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *", $append = FALSE);
}'. That Didn't solved the problem...

Comment: try the .htaccess version of it

Comment: @Dori Just read the docs for `drupal_add_http_header`, you aren't passing the correct parameters (also read up on how to pass parameters in PHP in general, your current method isn't great). It should be more like `drupal_add_http_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'domain.com');`